# How to integrate onclick listener on elements of Card in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to handle click listener in a Card, if I want to navigate to different destinations by clicking the various cards in LazyVertical Grid in android jetpack compose?

I am trying to implement if-else statement for handling all the cards link so I will expected to get the intended output when I click on specific card. But, when I'm trying to integrate NavHost fragment on *onClicklistener* it is giving me the error called

> "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function"

Below is the code
**Screens.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun gridview(context: Context) {

    lateinit var languageList:List<LanguageModel>
    languageList = ArrayList()


    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Greetings",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.wave)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Fruits",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.fruits)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Flower",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.sakura)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Numbers",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.numbers)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Family",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.family)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Months",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.calendar)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Sports",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.sports)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Time",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.clock)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Food",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.food)
    languageList = languageList+LanguageModel("Days",com.example.flashcardsapp.R.drawable.day)


    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
    ){

        items(languageList.size){
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            Card(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                onClick = {
                if (languageList[it].english=="Greetings"){
                    NavHost(navController =navController) // i am getting an error here. I want to go to a
                // different destination every time click on an element
                }else if (languageList[it].english=="Fruits"){

                }
            },
               modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),

                elevation = 6.dp
                ) {
                    Column(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(5.dp)
                            .background(Color(216, 191, 216)),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

                    ) {

                         Image(painter = painterResource(id = languageList[it].languageImage),
                             contentDescription = "Learn",
                             modifier = Modifier
                                 .height(60.dp)
                                 .width(60.dp)
                                 .padding(5.dp)
                             )
                        // on the below line we are adding a spacer.
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))

                         Text(text = languageList[it].english,
                              modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                             color = Color.Black,
                             fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                             )
                    }
                    
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

So I have mentioned the line where I am getting the mentioned the error

Answer (score 0):

You can learn full navigation from the below link. because the code you wrote is just a mess.

**https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/navigating-in-jetpack-compose-78c78d365c6a**

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I use NavHost in Card composable for onClick?